# Prevent application from monitoring other processes running on same machine

Tags: windows-7, windows, security, process

Is it possible for a 3rd party application running locally on a Windows 7/8/10 to monitor other services/processes running on the same machine?

If so, how would one prevent this?

Comment: What do you mean by "monitor"?  Like the list you get in Task Manager?

Comment: I meant that application could just "see" all other processes on local machine, their PIDs, name, cpu time etc, and store it somewhere and some how analyse this info.

Comment: Yes it is possible (firewalls and antivirus programs do exactly this). Yes you can prevent it (if you know it's name you can terminate it every time it starts up).

Comment: No, I don't want to terminate it, I want it running but prevent it from view other processes

Answer (score 0):

If you want to block a *specific* program, with a *specific* process name, then yes it is possible.

If you want to block the "monitoring" in general, then no, it is not possible, since those information are provided by the OS's APIs.

Comment: I don't want to block application generally, I want to block it's ability to view other processes running on the same machine. But still I want this app running.